# haml display address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

```
album/show.html.haml

    #comment_list= render :partial => 'shared/comments', :locals => { :commentable => @album }

shared/_comments.html.haml

    #comments
      = commentable.comments.each do |comment|
        = comment.content

display

    Hello #<Comment:0x7f668f037710>
```

why is address displaying? How to remove it?

Comment: +1 for "why adress is displaying?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you remove the = before commentable?
I think the parser understand that you are mixIng erb and haml. Try removing = and inserting - instead.

Comment: It's crash with "Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal."

Comment: @Вячеслав Логинов try replacing it with `-`. I'm assuming `comment.content` is "Hello", then the `each` block returns the last comment as it's value, which gets printed because you use `=`.

Comment: @Matt ah sorry hijacked your answer by responding to OP without seeing your comment.